# Comprehending wiring data sheet for ME3 C2H4 gas sensor

Tags: arduino, datasheet, wiring, arduino-uno, gas-sensor

[image: datasheet]I am humbly requesting an English translation of this image. The only thing I figured out is that the box on the top left is the ME3 sensor I am trying to connect to an Arduino. It has three pins, as indicated by the reference sheet. But aside from that, nothing on here tells me anything about how to connect this to an Arduino Uno. All I need is for you to identify the pins of the sensor. Anything extra would be greatly appreciated but thats all.
Thanks greatly in advance.
The link of the pdf image of the sensor I am using is: [pdf image link](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Electrochemical%20Gas%20Sensor/4-series%20Electrochemical/ME3-C2H4%200-100ppm%20Manual.pdf)

Comment: post link without the http

Comment: I think you forgot the image! Please click on the "edit" link below your question, and add the image to the question.

Comment: that is a schematic diagram ..... it is not language dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

These sensors need a custom design of a small circuit board to create a linear response to Arduino.

- C = Common electrode
- W = Working electrode
- R = Reference electrode
  [image]

### Datasheet

https://www.winsen-sensor.com/d/files/PDF/Electrochemical%20Gas%20Sensor/4-series%20Electrochemical/ME3-C2H4%200-100ppm%20Manual.pdf

### - consider a better sensor and SDK

http://info.ionscience.com/sensor-development-kit-sdk

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm afraid that I can't use those sensors since I am doing a household project and I can't seem to find any sensors for C2H4 "ethylene". Aside from the board, would you be able to tell me what the pins stand for ( which one is GND,etc.) Thank you.

Comment: There is no ground

Comment: Ok thank you but what does the C, R , and W stand for? I've never seen a 3-pin sensor before.

Comment: Thank you so much. All I need to find ou tnow is how to connect to Arduino Uno, which isn't too hard. P.S I think C stands for counter electrode instead of common. AKA auxiliary electrode.

Comment: It won't work connecting to an arduino unless you make the above interface, yet there is no counter and it does not interface to user.  It is just a common connection Driven by U1A so effectively it becomes the 0V gnd but you cant use the Arduino 0V gnd

Comment: Ok, so what would I need to connect it to an arduino? I'm sorry if this is really broad, but it's the best I can do.

Comment: the above schematic for starters then research on Rt temperature compensation and a lot more experience